# Find greatest value from 4 columns and assign label to it in EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

In EXCEL I have 1728 rows and 4 columns. in each row from 4 columns i need to find greatest value and then assign it a label.

Example:

```
J             K           L              M
===================================================
0.257381111 0.240049322 0.241308963 **0.261260605**
0.256963712 0.240619964 0.241812186 **0.260604138**
0.243534208 **0.258505469** 0.257283414 0.240676909
```

In first row greatest is shown in bold so answer should be 4. Similarly in rest 2 cases answer should be 4, 2 respectively. It is to be assigned as J=1, K=2, L=3 and M=4

Below formula does not work:
   =IF(J3>K3,1,IF(K3>L3,2,IF(L3>M3,3,4)))

Comment: Is it possible to have a duplicate number?  If so, and that number happens to be the maximum number, what column number do you want labelled?

Answer (score 1):

Use the MATCH formula:

```
=MATCH(MAX($J1:$M1),$J1:$M1,0)
```

[image]